# Disable showing same input value on different components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making a todo app where I can add new comments on the already present todos. The problems is that when I type a new comment, the same input is shown on all the other input fields for new todo comments. I know that it's doing that because I set the value of the input fields to have the same state value.

```
const [inputComment, setInputComment] = useState('');
```

Here is the code for the new comment section of the todo component

```
 <Box sx={{ marginTop: "10px", display: "flex", alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "space-between" }}>
        <TextField
            id="standard-basic"
            placeholder="Enter comment:"
            variant="standard"
            value={inputComment}
            onChange={event => setInputComment(event.target.value)}
        />
        <AddCommentIcon className="icon" sx={{ alignSelf: "flex-end", fontSize: "1.3rem" }} onClick={() => { AddComment(todo.id, inputComment) }} />
</Box>
```

**How can I disable showing the same input on the other input fields?**

This is the full code:

```
import React from "react";
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { db } from "../firebase-config";
import { collection, getDocs, deleteDoc, addDoc, getDoc, updateDoc, doc, query, orderBy, arrayUnion, arrayRemove } from "firebase/firestore";

import List from '@mui/material/List';
import ListItem from '@mui/material/ListItem';
import Divider from '@mui/material/Divider';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import MoreHorizIcon from '@mui/icons-material/MoreHoriz';
import Accordion from '@mui/material/Accordion';
import AccordionSummary from '@mui/material/AccordionSummary';
import AccordionDetails from '@mui/material/AccordionDetails';
import ExpandMoreIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ExpandMore';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import AddCommentIcon from '@mui/icons-material/AddCommentOutlined';
import DeleteOutlineIcon from '@mui/icons-material/DeleteOutline';
import Snackbar from '@mui/material/Snackbar';
import IconButton from '@mui/material/IconButton';
import CloseIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Close';
import EditIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Edit';
import ModeCommentIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ModeComment';
import Badge from "@mui/material/Badge";

import todopic from "../img/undraw_completing_re_i7ap.svg"
import { async } from "@firebase/util";


//start of the TodoList component
export default function TodoList() {

    //useStates
    const [newTodos, setNewTodos] = useState([]);
    //const [finishedTodos, setFinishedTodos] = useState([]);
    const [inputComment, setInputComment] = useState('');

    //style for the list component
    const style = {
        width: '100%',
        maxWidth: 360,
        bgcolor: 'background.paper',
    };

    //getting the link to the db
    const todosRef = collection(db, "todos");
    //const finishedTodosRef = collection(db, "finishedTodos");

    //get the db data
    useEffect(() => {
        const getTodos = async () => {
            const q = query(todosRef, orderBy("timestamp", "desc"));
            const data = await getDocs(q);
            setNewTodos(data.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })))
        }
        getTodos();
    }, [])

    // useEffect(() => {
    //     const getFinishedTodos = async () => {
    //         const q = query(todosRef, orderBy("timestamp", "desc"));
    //         const data = await getDocs(q);
    //         setFinishedTodos(data.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })))
    //     }
    //     getFinishedTodos();
    // }, [])

    //delete a todo
    const deleteTodo = async (id) => {
        const todoDoc = doc(db, "todos", id);
        await deleteDoc(todoDoc);
        window.location.reload();
    }

    // const finishTodo = async (id) => {
    //     const todoDoc = doc(db, "todos", id);
    //     const docSnap = await getDoc(todoDoc);
    //     let todoText = docSnap.data().text;
    //     await deleteDoc(todoDoc);
    //     await addDoc(finishedTodosRef, {
    //         text: todoText
    //     });
    //     window.location.reload();
    // }

    // const deleteFinishedTodo = async (id) => {
    //     const finisedTodoDoc = doc(db, "finishedTodos", id);
    //     await deleteDoc(finisedTodoDoc);
    //     window.location.reload();
    // }

    //add a comment for a todo
    const AddComment = async (id, newComment) => {
        const todoDoc = doc(db, "todos", id);
        if (newComment == "") {
            setOpen(true);
        } else {
            await updateDoc(todoDoc, {
                "comments": arrayUnion(newComment)
            });
            window.location.reload();
        }
    }

    //delete a comment of a todo
    const deleteComment = async (id, comment) => {
        const todoDoc = doc(db, "todos", id);
        await updateDoc(todoDoc, {
            comments: arrayRemove(comment)
        });
        window.location.reload();
    }

    //state for opening component
    const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

    const handleClose = (event, reason) => {
        if (reason === 'clickaway') {
            return;
        }
        setOpen(false);
    };

    //action for the snackbar component
    const action = (
        <React.Fragment>
            <IconButton
                size="small"
                aria-label="close"
                color="inherit"
                onClick={handleClose}
            >
                <CloseIcon fontSize="small" />
            </IconButton>
        </React.Fragment>
    );

    //start to render the db items
    //if no items render this
    if (newTodos.length == 0) {
        return (
            <div className="no-todos">
                <p>You are all done!</p>
                <img src={todopic} alt="todopic" />
            </div>
        )
        //if you have items render this
    } else {
        return (
            <div style={{ position: "relative", overflow: "hidden" }}>
                <List
                    sx={{
                        width: '100%',
                        maxWidth: 360,
                        bgcolor: 'background.paper',
                    }}
                >
                    {/* start of mapping out each indivudal item */}
                    {newTodos.map((todo) => (
                        <div key={todo.id}>
                            <Accordion sx={{
                                margin: "10px 0"
                            }}>
                                <AccordionSummary
                                    expandIcon={<MoreHorizIcon />}
                                    aria-controls="panel1a-content"
                                    id="panel1a-header"
                                >
                                    <Typography style={{ color: todo.importance == "Primary" ? "#ff3333" : "black" }}>{todo.text}</Typography>
                                </AccordionSummary>
                                <AccordionDetails>
                                    <Typography variant="body2">
                                        Due until: {todo.dueDate}
                                    </Typography>
                                    <Typography variant="body2">Importance: {todo.importance}</Typography>
                                    <Accordion style={{
                                        margin: "10px 0"
                                    }}>
                                        <AccordionSummary
                                            expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
                                            aria-controls="panel1a-content"
                                            id="panel1a-header"
                                        >
                                            <Badge badgeContent={todo.comments.length} color="primary">
                                                <ModeCommentIcon style={{ fontSize: "1.3rem" }} color="action" />
                                            </Badge>
                                        </AccordionSummary>
                                        <AccordionDetails>
                                            <List sx={style}>
                                                {todo.comments.map(comment => {
                                                    return (
                                                        <Box key={comment}>
                                                            <ListItem style={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "space-between" }}>
                                                                <Typography variant="caption">{comment}</Typography>
                                                                <DeleteOutlineIcon className="icon" onClick={() => deleteComment(todo.id, comment)} />
                                                            </ListItem>
                                                            <Divider />
                                                        </Box>
                                                    )
                                                })}
                                                <Box sx={{ marginTop: "10px", display: "flex", alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "space-between" }}>
                                                    <TextField
                                                        id="standard-basic"
                                                        placeholder="Enter comment:"
                                                        variant="standard"
                                                        value={inputComment}
                                                        onChange={event => setInputComment(event.target.value)}
                                                    />
                                                    <AddCommentIcon className="icon" sx={{ alignSelf: "flex-end", fontSize: "1.3rem" }} onClick={() => { AddComment(todo.id, inputComment) }} />
                                                </Box>
                                            </List>
                                        </AccordionDetails>
                                    </Accordion>
                                    <DeleteOutlineIcon className="icon" onClick={() => deleteTodo(todo.id)} />
                                    <EditIcon sx={{ marginLeft: "10px" }} className="icon" />
                                </AccordionDetails>
                            </Accordion>
                            <Divider />
                        </div>
                    ))}
                </List>
                <div>
                    <Snackbar
                        open={open}
                        autoHideDuration={3000}
                        onClose={handleClose}
                        message="Can't enter an empty comment!"
                        action={action}
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }//end of else statement
} //end of main component
```

Comment: what is stopping you from using an `if` condition in your template?

Comment: I thought about using that method, but I'm not sure where should I put it. @Prajwal

Comment: can you show full code?

Comment: @iamhuynq I posted the full code.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a `InputComment` component and put `inputComment` state inside it

**InputComment**

```
const InputComment = ({ AddComment }) => {
    const [inputComment, setInputComment] = useState('');
    return (
        <Box
            sx={{
                marginTop: '10px',
                display: 'flex',
                alignItems: 'center',
                justifyContent: 'space-between',
            }}
        >
            <TextField
                id="standard-basic"
                placeholder="Enter comment:"
                variant="standard"
                value={inputComment}
                onChange={(event) => setInputComment(event.target.value)}
            />
            <AddCommentIcon
                className="icon"
                sx={{ alignSelf: 'flex-end', fontSize: '1.3rem' }}
                onClick={() => {
                    AddComment(inputComment);
                }}
            />
        </Box>
    );
};
```

**TodoList**

```
<AccordionDetails>
    <List sx={style}>
        {todo.comments.map((comment) => {
            return (
                <Box key={comment}>
                    <ListItem
                        style={{
                            display: 'flex',
                            alignItems: 'center',
                            justifyContent: 'space-between',
                        }}
                    >
                        <Typography variant="caption">{comment}</Typography>
                        <DeleteOutlineIcon
                            className="icon"
                            onClick={() => deleteComment(todo.id, comment)}
                        />
                    </ListItem>
                    <Divider />
                </Box>
            );
        })}
        <InputComment AddComment={(comment) => AddComment(todo.id, comment)} />
    </List>
</AccordionDetails>
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried using **ternary operators** and <code>if<code> statements, but nothing worked. I also thought about making a separate component, but I wanted to try some shorter solutions.

Comment: I think its better to making separate component, if you put inputComment in todoList, when you change input, it will re-render whole todolist component because inputComment  state change. If you put inputComment  inside separate component, only that component re-render when  state change. So better performance @LukaMiljković